# Change element css if a custom attribute has a specific value jquery

Tags: jquery

Why the css applies to all the elements with that class even with that if statement ?
Is something wrong?

```
if( $( '.simply-drop-menu' ).attr( 'data-type-simply-menu' ) == 'user_friends-request' ) {
        $( '.simply-drop-menu' ).css({
            'top': '130px',
            'right': '21px',
            'opacity': '0',
            'pointer-events': 'none'
        });
    }
```

Comment: If you're using JQuery >= 1.4.3, you could do:  `$( '.simply-drop-menu' ).data('type-simply-menu')`.  This has nothing to do with your problem -- just something I noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the if-statement evaluates as true, the selector that is being used `.simply-drop-down` will target all elements with that class and apply the appropriate properties to them :

```
// This will target every element with the class 'simply-drop-down'
$('.simply-drop-menu').css({
        'top': '130px',
        'right': '21px',
        'opacity': '0',
        'pointer-events': 'none'
});
```

**Consider an Attribute Selector**

Instead you might want to consider using [the attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to only target those elements with that specific attribute value :

```
// This will target all elements with the class 'simply-drop-down' that have a data 
// attribute of 'data-type-simply-menu' with a value of 'user_friends-request'
$('.simply-drop-menu[data-type-simply-menu="user_friends-request"]').css({
        'top': '130px',
        'right': '21px',
        'opacity': '0',
        'pointer-events': 'none'
});
```

This also eliminates the need for an if-statement to be used as well.

**Example**

[image]

```js
// This will only target your drop down elements with the proper attribute value
$('.simply-drop-menu[data-type-simply-menu="user_friends-request"]').css({
  'color': 'red'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>Notice only the simply-drop-down class with the appropriate data attribute is red.</pre>
<div class='simply-drop-menu' data-type-simply-menu="user_friends-request">class='simply-drop-menu' data-type-simply-menu="user_friends-request"</div>
<div class='simply-drop-menu'>class='simply-drop-menu'</div>
<div data-type-simply-menu="user_friends-request">data-type-simply-menu="user_friends-request"</div>
<div class='simply-drop-menu' data-type-simply-menu="user_friends-foo">class='simply-drop-menu' data-type-simply-menu="user_friends-foo"</div>
```

Comment: This isn't using any CSS. It's using a jQuery selector to select the appropriate elements by their attribute and then calling the `css()` function on those elements.

Comment: I've added an example which should clarify exactly what is going on.

Comment: [data-type-simply-menu="user_friends-request"] this is css thing used through jquery. Anyway, i've tried and it doesn't work

Comment: No it isn't. This is a JQuery attribute selector which is selecting your elements that have that attribute with that value. In this case a `data-*` attribute is being used, but you could use an `id`, `title` or whatever you would like. Have you seen the example? It clearly demonstrates how this works. Consider posting sone of your markup if you want a more specific example.

Comment: I've seen the example but for me stills not working, why? :(

Comment: Could you post a snippet of what your current markup looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You're right. Had to use the `.attr()` method. More study needed, I s'pose.

Try it like this:

```js
$('#checkit').click(function(){
  alert( $('.simply-drop-menu').attr('data-simplyMenu') );
   if ($('.simply-drop-menu').attr('data-simplyMenu') == 'user_friends-request') {
     //disabled opacity because you cannot see it work
     $('.simply-drop-menu').css({'top': '130px','right': '21px','opacity': '','pointer-events': 'none'});
     $('.simply-drop-menu').css('background','yellow');
   }
});

1
```

```css
.simply-drop-menu{position:relative;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="simply-drop-menu" data-simplyMenu="user_friends-request" type="text" />

<button id="checkit">Check It</button>
```

> For example, given the following HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>
```

> All of the following jQuery code will work.

```
$( "div" ).data( "role" ) === "page";
$( "div" ).data( "lastValue" ) === 43;
$( "div" ).data( "hidden" ) === true;
$( "div" ).data( "options" ).name === "John";
```

Reference:

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I have more study to do myself. Data doesn't work the way i remembered.

Comment: Here's [another example to review](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_data)